# Vue.js | Filters is not return

Tags: vue.js, pagekit

I have a problem.

I am posting a category id with http post. status is returning a data that is true. I want to return with the value count variable from the back. But count does not go back. Return in function does not work. the value in the function does not return from the outside.

category-index -> View

```
<td>{{category.id | count}}</td>
```

Controller File

```
/**
* @Access(admin=true)
* @Route(methods="POST")
* @Request({"id": "integer"}, csrf=true)
*/
public function countAction($id){
 return ['status'  => 'yes'];
}
```

Vue File

```
filters: {
 count: function(data){
  var count = '';
  this.$http.post('/admin/api/dpnblog/category/count' , {id:data} , function(success){
    count = success.status;
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log('error')
  })
  return count;
 }
}
```

**But not working :(**

Thank you guys.

Comment: Simple Example https://jsfiddle.net/Bigchefstarys/eqanx2rh/

but The value in `this.$http.post` function is not working.

Comment: ajax is an asynchronous operation, so count return as '' before data coming

Comment: You should revise how promises work in Javascript. `return count` will be executed immediately before the promise has resolved. This is not what filters are for.

Comment: @Chibiao.Wang Could you give me an example?

Comment: I have given an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view

```
<td>{{count}}</td>
```

vue

```
data() {
    return {
      count: '',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // or in any other Controller, and set your id this function
    this.countFunc()
  },
  methods: {
    countFunc: function(data) {
      this.$http
        .post('/admin/api/dpnblog/category/count', { id: data }, function(
          success,
        ) {
          // update view
          this.count = success.status
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('error')
        })
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: Since you're using `<td>` it implies that you have a whole table of these; you might want to consider getting them all at once to reduce the amount of back-end calls.

Filters are meant for simple in-place string modifications like formatting etc.
Consider using a method to fetch this instead.

template

```
<td>{{ categoryCount }}</td>
```

script

```
data() {
  return {
     categoryCount: ''
  }
},
created() {
  this.categoryCount = this.fetchCategoryCount()
},
methods: {
 async fetchCategoryCount() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$http.post('/admin/api/dpnblog/category/count', {id: this.category.id})
    return response.status;
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('error')
  }
 }
}
```